# Compatibility Wikittude with Telerik

Tags: android, ios, mobile, telerik, wikitude

We are researching if Wikitude is compatible with the Telerik platform.
We have searched the Forums on Stackoverflow, Wikitude and Telerik, and the only answer we got was it is possible, with no explanation how to do it.Furthermore no-one has said: "I got it working" and there where only questions how to do it. We found 1 instance where a Telerik admin has helped someone to make it work, but the problem with the post was that the original poster didn't make it clear if it was working at the end.

I link the useable forumposts we found:

[icenium-graphite-and-wikitude](http://www.telerik.com/forums/icenium-graphite-and-wikitude)

Furthermore we found an other forum that was older than the other one I linked. In this post an admin said the the plugin was not compatible at that moment, we haven't found the follow-up on that forum post. this is the link

[wikitude-support](http://www.telerik.com/forums/wikitude-support)

With kind regards.

Comment: I have an other link [custom-plugin-headache](http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-plugin-headache)